# Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 store prohibited in ESP32

Tags: uart, modbus, esp32

https://github.com/shubhamshirsode/ESP32_BYN.git

Above URL code runs on ESp8266 with SoftSerial but when I run on ESP32 LORA Heltec model. It gives me "Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 store prohibited"

My question is Can we use software serial in ESP32 if yes then tell me what is problem in above code.

If not then please give me another solution.

I want to get data through Modbus RTU protocol on ESP32 heltec model.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You should the code you are having problems with. Not just a link to the code.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you but i have given link to check my code because I don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Searching on Github  found a [library](https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial) that solves the problem.

My theory is that some SoftwareSerial implementations uses CLI and SEI macros, this blocks the FreeRTOS and triggers the exception.